# Neat solution to convert flat data to nested JSON

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Can anyone help with this task, please.  Searches so far haven't really helped me get started.  Two approaches tried but hit snags, an expanded object expression like:

```
function getGroupData() {

return [...Array(Math.ceil(Math.random()*MAXLINES)).keys()].map(i => ({

label: 'label' + (i+1),

      data: getSegmentsData()
})

and the push method:
{
                "group": group,
                "data": [{
                    "label": label, "data": [{"timeRange": [
                            { "start": start, "finish": finish }]
                    }]
                }]

            }

            myData.push(group);
        }
```

The former seems like a neat idea but I can't find how to feed in the flat data.  The flat array and desired outcome are below.

```
var myData = [{group: "group1",
                              data: [{
                                  label: "label1", data: [
                                                           { timeRange: ["07-10-2013", "06-12-2013"]},
                                                           { timeRange: ["11-05-2013", "11-06-2013"]},
                                                           { timeRange: ["06-07-2013", "07-08-2013"]}]}]}]



 var myFlatData = [
    { group: "group1", label: "label1", start: "01/06/2018", finish: "01/06/2018"},
    { group: "group2", label: "label1", start: "02/07/2018", finish: "02/07/2018"}
```

Comment: `d3.nest`. How to get from 2018 dates to 2013 dates and where is group2

Comment: These are just date examples but show the desired structure.  I have tried d3.nest but can't get it to nest under data 'key'!  e.g  myData.data.data.timeRange

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works but not very elegant or efficient!

```
function flatTOnested(nDATA) {

    var MAXCATEGORIES = 20
    var categoryLabels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'];
    var nCategories = Math.ceil(Math.random() * MAXCATEGORIES)
    var myData = [];

    var gps = nDATA.map(function(d) {
            return d.group;
        })
        .reduce(function(p, v) {
            return p.indexOf(v) == -1 ? p.concat(v) : p;
        }, [])
        .filter(function(d) {
            return (typeof d !== "undefined") ? d !== null : false
        });
    var i = 0
    gps.forEach(function(gp) {

        var datar = nDATA.filter(function(d) {
            return d.group === gp;
        });

        var group = {
            "group": gp,
            "data": []
        }

        myData.push(group)

        var labels = datar.map(function(d) {
                return d.label;
            })
            .reduce(function(p, v) {
                return p.indexOf(v) == -1 ? p.concat(v) : p;
            }, [])
            .filter(function(d) {
                return (typeof d !== "undefined") ? d !== null : false
            });

        var ii = 0
        labels.forEach(function(lab) {

            var sublab = datar.filter(function(d) {
                return d.label === lab;
            });

            var lvl2 = {
                "label": lab,
                "data": []
            }

            myData[i].data.push(lvl2)

            for (var j = 0, jlen = sublab.length; j < jlen; j++) {

                var lvl3 = {
                    "timeRange": [],
                    "description": sublab[j].description,
                    "labelVal": sublab[j].labelVal,
                    "val": sublab[j].val //categoryLabels[Math.ceil(Math.random() * nCategories)]
                }

                myData[i].data[ii].data.push(lvl3)

                var start = sublab[j].start
                var finish = sublab[j].finish

                var lvl4 = start

                myData[i].data[ii].data[j].timeRange.push(lvl4)

                var lvl4 = finish

                myData[i].data[ii].data[j].timeRange.push(lvl4)

            }

            ii++
        })

        i++
    });

    return myData
}
```